# convert multidimensional array to nested vector in clojure?

Tags: multidimensional-array, clojure

[to-array-2D](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/to-array-2d) is a handy function for converting a collection of collections into a 2D java array. Is there a function to go the other way?

I would like to get a vector of vectors from a 2D java array.

Comment: Maybe something like `(mapv (partial into []) my-array)`

Comment: good enough for me! thanks! post an answer and i'll upvote

Comment: It's ok. You've already got a better answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
(mapv vec the-array)
```

Although in that case, take into account the documentation of `vec`

> clojure.core/vec
>   ([coll])
>     Creates a new vector containing the contents of coll. Java arrays
>     will be aliased and should not be modified.

If you prefer to make a copy (less efficient but safer), do what leeor says in the comment. Shorter version:

```
(mapv #(into [] %) the-array)
```